# How to access .h file information from C#

Tags: c#, c, parsing, header-files

When using the NI tools to create a FPGA bit file, LabView generates a C .h file that contains information for communicating to the FPGA application such as the signature (a const) and the register addresses (as enums).

The challenge is that my application is written in C# and I **need** access to those register addresses.

The only options I can think of are:

1. Cut-and-paste the contents of the .h file into a .cs file ~~~~ ... gives me the shivers,  C# is one developer and FPGA is another.
2. Parse the .h file  ~~~~ ... gives me the shivers too - writing my own language parser :(

There has got to be a better way!!!

Sample .h:

```
 /*
 * Generated with the FPGA Interface C API Generator 12.0.0
 * for NI-RIO 12.0.0 or later.
 */

#ifndef __NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_h__
#define __NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_h__

#ifndef NiFpga_Version
   #define NiFpga_Version 1200
#endif

#include "NiFpga.h"

/**
 * The filename of the FPGA bitfile.
 *
 * This is a #define to allow for string literal concatenation. For example:
 *
 *    static const char* const Bitfile = "C:\\" NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Bitfile;
 */
#define NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Bitfile "NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA.lvbitx"

/**
 * The signature of the FPGA bitfile.
 */
static const char* const NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Signature = "D0751ADE3A0EC976606D63C425B35E85";

typedef enum
{
   NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_IndicatorBool_FallingEdge = 0x8132,
   NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_IndicatorBool_StopSignal = 0x813A,
} NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_IndicatorBool;

....

#endif
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the .h file?

Comment: If it's simple enough, regex. Otherwise gcc-xml

Comment: How is the best way to post the example .h file?

Comment: Just put a small, indicative sample of it in your answer and use the "format as code" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a C++/CLI project to the solution that includes the .h file and exposes the information through managed static methods.

```
public ref class OTRM_Ovd_FPGA
{
public:
    static System::String^ GetFilename() { return gcnew System::String(NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Bitfile);};
    static System::String^ GetSignature() { return gcnew System::String(NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Signature);};

    enum class RegisterAddress : System::UInt16
    {
        InitialPulseAmplitude = NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_IndicatorU16_ExtPulseAmplitudeDisplay,
        CurrentPulseAmplitude = NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_IndicatorU16_ExtPulseAmplitudeDisplay,
        PulseAmplitudeDecrement = NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_ControlU16_Decrement_Step,
        PollPeriod = NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_ControlI16_Frequency_ms,
        HvprotState = NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_ControlI16_HVProt,
        PaceThreshold = NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_ControlI16_VVIThreshold,
    };
};
```

Comment: Ultimately this is going to work out really well.  Eventually I can move the FPGA files (including the generated .h file) out of the Application build into the FPGA build and make the Application build dependent on the FPGA build.  Then the FPGA developer can work in his space without any concerns about what builds use his work ... that is, until he breaks their build - which will be caught by the build server which will automatically send him, the application developer (and me) an email.  NICE (IMHO)

Comment: Thanks Keith, getting the syntax to get this to work was a lot more of the effort than I expected so I wanted to show the actual solution.

Comment: One ugly part of this solution is that it is x86 only.
To make it support x64 you have to compile it with /clr:safe.
Unfortunately, /clr:safe does not allow pointers (a char* is used in the .h I have to include to define a string).
So close; but so far.

Answer (score 0):

given its likely only a tiny subset of things you need to parse, in fact, it won't have to parse but probably just do a few text manipulations / search replaces. It shouldn't be too hard.  Also, you can use C++.NET to wrap the things into an API you can use from C#.

Also you may want to look at something like 'SWIG'

http://www.swig.org/

Comment: "C++.NET" Do you mean C++/CLI

Comment: I don't want updating the FPGA to require a code change (build update at worst).

Comment: it won't, unless it changes?

Comment: I did think of C++.NET / C++/CLI; but I believe it has been officially discontinued by Microsoft.

Comment: I can't assure the file won't change.  The register addresses are auto selected and the .h is auto generated.

Comment: right, and if it changed then YOU HAVE TO compile your C# right? otherwise they will be out of sync?

Comment: The build server would initiate the recompile - that is not a problem, I just don't want a manual step.

Comment: normally there shouldn't be a manual step, other than if the interface changes, but then you'd be changing your C# code to use the new thing / not use the thing that changed, or use it in a different way.  But if the code just changes where everything is, then its just a recompile

Comment: basically, you can manually roll the interface in C++/CLI, good option if the interface basically doesn't change, or use SWIG to auto generate the interface, or roll your own thing that will generate the interface.

Comment: By interface, I mean if the names of the registers aren't changing ( but theirlocations might ) then you have a pretty stable interface

Comment: OK, my misunderstanding that C++/CLI was not an option.
I am trying that now.

Comment: OK, so now down to syntax.  If I want to have a method that returns a cli string for the NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Signature in the .h, how do I do that?  I tried this, but my syntax must be wrong:
    public ref class OTRM_Ovd_FPGA
    {
    public:
        static const char* GetSignature() { return NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Signature;};
    };

Comment: Keith, I am still confused about what exactly Microsoft has deprecated.  I thought C++ Managed Extensions were the C++ language extensions required to allow for the syntax needed to declare managed C++ code.  Clearly I needed the ^ to and the ref class (which I do not believe are part of C++ per ANSI) to get my code to work; so C++/CLI does extend the C++ language to support managed code.